# standalone compaction in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, tombstone

I am fairly new to Cassandra, so plz excuse if you find this question not worthy.

I am trying to test the behavior of my cassandra(1.2.5) cluster, for that i have set my column ttl to be 1 day. After a day i was able to confirm the data being not available, but i want to verify that standalone compaction is happening and cleaning the space occupied by tombstones when i am using default tombstone_threshold i.e 20%.

So my question is  - How to make sure Stand alone compaction is happening? and is there a way to know how much size disk space is freed in the process. Is there any logs reading about the compaction type and the work done by compaction?

Answer (score 1):

If you insert a little data (im talking 5-10 rows) it will be very easy to track whats going on via the sstable2json tool which gives you a 'raw' view of what an sstable stores. For detailed statistics about the ks/cf use **nodetool status** where you can see each node's **load**.

```
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address    Load       Tokens  Owns (effective)  Host ID         Rack
UN  127.0.0.1  90.87 KB   256     100.0%            a0a2...22ff     rack1
```

Comment: You can also see ongoing compactions through `nodetool compactionstats`.

Comment: **nodetool compactionstats**, just prints the ongoing compaction statics so not much help. And also it dosnt  say the type stanalone/layered/size_tired of compaction going on.

Comment: Similarly **nodetool status** talks about the cluster health, and not compaction strategies